# How to retain number of digits for the variable in a for-loop

Tags: c#, variables, for-loop

I wish to keep three digits for the variable in a for loop. E.g.

```
for (int i = 002; i <= 033; i++)
{
      string localFilename = @"\\psf\Home\Pictures\Maulavi\" + i + ".jpg";
      using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
      {
           MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
           client.DownloadFile("http://eap.bl.uk/EAPDigitalItems/EAP566/EAP566_1_1_19_2-EAP566_Maulvi_January_1946_v43_no2_" + i + "_L.jpg", localFilename);
      }
}
```

However I changes to being just `2` and `3` etc. I want it to stay as `002` and `003` etc. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `i.ToString("D3")` or `i.ToString("000")`.

For more information on number to string conversions, have a look at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try `ToString("000")` like this:

```
for (int i = 002; i <= 033; i++)
{
    ....
    ....
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString("000")); // 002 , 003 , ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Format string with overload of function `ToString()`:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 33; i++)
{
    string localFilename = @"\\psf\Home\Pictures\Maulavi\" + i.ToString("000") + ".jpg";
}
```

Or you can use `Format` function:

```
String.Format("{0:000}", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string.Format(@"\psf\Home\Pictures\Maulavi{0:000}.jpg", i)

Format will also have better performance than string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Use like following it's works as you want:

```
        char padChar = '0';
        for (int i = 002; i <= 033; i++)
        {
            string localFilename = @"\\psf\Home\Pictures\Maulavi\" + i + ".jpg";
            string padStr = i.ToString().PadLeft(3,padChar);
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
                client.DownloadFile("http://eap.bl.uk/EAPDigitalItems/EAP566/EAP566_1_1_19_2-EAP566_Maulvi_January_1946_v43_no2_" + padStr + "_L.jpg", localFilename);
            }
        }
```

For more about this visit: http://mahedee.net/padding-character-with-string/